# Magento 2: Get orders by payment method

Tags: magento2

I am using the below code in my block to fetch all orders ,

```
public function getOrders()
    {
        if (!($customerId = ObjectManager::getInstance()
                ->create('Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory')->create()
                ->getCustomer()->getId())) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!$this->orders) {
            $this->orders = $this->getOrderCollectionFactory()->create($customerId)->addFieldToSelect(
                '*'
            )->addFieldToFilter(
                'status',
                ['in' => $this->_orderConfig->getVisibleOnFrontStatuses()]
            )->setOrder(
                'created_at',
                'desc'
            );
        }
        return $this->orders;
    }
```

**How can I add a filter to it to fetch all orders by a payment method?**

I have tried using

> addFieldToFilter('method','ccsave');

But it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot  directly filter order collection by payment method.

To achieve, this you should do a **mysql join** on database table `sales_order_payment` with **your order collection**.

```
if (!$this->orders) {
    $pMethod = 'ccsave';

    $this->orders = $this->getOrderCollectionFactory()->create($customerId)->addFieldToSelect(
        '*'
    )->addFieldToFilter(
        'status',
        ['in' => $this->_orderConfig->getVisibleOnFrontStatuses()]
    );
    /* join with payment table */
    $this->orders->getSelect()
    ->join(
        ["sop" => "sales_order_payment"],
        'main_table.entity_id = sop.parent_id',
        array('method')
    )
    ->where('sop.method = ?',$pMethod );

    $this->orders->setOrder(
        'created_at',
        'desc'
    );

}
```

Comment: not able to apply getData() method after joining. How to fetch data after joining?