# How to get list of orders filtering by payment method

Tags: magento2, collection

I would like to get a list of orders which have been made by a specific payment method using the search criteria. Is there any way we can achieve this?

The only thing I've found is this thread: [Magento 2: Get orders by payment method](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/203637/magento-2-get-orders-by-payment-method), which doesn't use searchCriteria. I would like to understand how to do this type of search/join between tables and models in magento 2.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

add a new extension attribute to the order:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface">
        <attribute code="payment_method" type="string" >
            <join reference_table="sales_order_payment" reference_field="parent_id" join_on_field="entity_id">
                <field>method</field>
            </join>
        </attribute>
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

then use OrderRepository as per your requirement:

```
$filter = $this->filterBuilder->setField('extension_attribute_payment_method.method')
            ->setConditionType('eq')
            ->setValue($methodCode)
            ->create();

        $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder
            ->addFilters([$filter])
            ->create();

        $orderList = $this->orderRepository->getList($searchCriteria);

        $numberOrders = $orderList->getTotalCount();
        $result = $orderList->getItems();
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked like a charm :)

Comment: thanks for the feedback, great question that was as It makes me getting on with repository and extension attributes a bit more..

Comment: wonderful. but what was the reason to create extension attribute for this. I mean can not we create joins directly in SearchCriteria?

Comment: The payment method data is not part of the order repository data. This solution exposes this data via an extension attribute. I did find this to be a simple way to add this data. Joins may work too but you’d have likely more hands on code to add I imagine